# iPhone Facebook SDK - Cannot post to friends wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm attempting to post to a `Facebook` friend's wall using the `Graph API`. But instead of posting to my friend's wall it returns all his `wall posts`. I've attached the code I'm using below and from searching other similar questions it seems like my code is correct.

I've also already set the correct `permissions` (`read_stream` & `publish_stream`). Does anyone have any ideas?

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = 
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"some test text",
                                                      @"message",
                                                      @"123456789",
                                                      @"target_id",nil];

[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed",@"123456789"] 
                          andParams:params 
                        andDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you try like this ,

```
[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"123456789/feed" 
                          andParams:params 
                      andHttpMethod:@"POST" 
                        andDelegate:self];
```

Because it seems, You are not adding method attribute

Comment: Thanks very much :) cant believe that I overlooked something so simple!